# Find the size of the center of a doughnut chart - achartengine

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I want to have clickable regions inside of my doughnut chart using aChartEngine, but this is not yet and implemented feature. I think I have a way to implement this so I'm planning out the pieces I need. The one part that I'm not sure about is how to get the size of the hole in the center of the chart. Specifically, I need to know the inner radius to ignore clicks in that area. Does someone know how this is decided? I tried looking through some of the source code but I couldn't quite find what I needed. Let me know if I can add any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse engineer it from https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/src/org/achartengine/chart/DoughnutChart.java:

Basically the radius of the inner circle can be calculated as follows:

```
int shortestSide = Math.min(Math.abs(right - left), Math.abs(bottom - top));
int originalRadius = (int) (0.35 * shortestSide);
int finalRadius = (int) (originalRadius - (0.2 * shortestSide + 1 * numCategories));
```

Where final radius is the radius of the inner circle. At least that works for me.

Comment: Also, the design for PieChart may help in doing the same thing for the DoughnutChart: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/src/org/achartengine/chart/PieChart.java

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thanks a ton. My clickable doughnut graph is now functional!